# Apps script : The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following client side app script html page:

```
  <body>

   <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">


  <div>
  <label for="optionList">Click me</label>
  <select id="optionList" name="email">
  <option>Loading...</option>    
  </select>

  </div>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">



  </script>
  <script>
  // This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
        .getAllOptions();  

  });


  function buildOptionList(options) {
    var list = $('#optionList');


    list.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    console.log(options[i]);
      list.append('<option value="' + options[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
  //        list.append('<option value="' + options[i]["email"] + '">' '</option>');


    }
  };


  </script>


    </body>
```

I am trying to send over all the rows of the spreadsheet as JS objects from a spreadsheet on the server side using:

```
  function getAllOptions() {

       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
    var main_range = mainSheet.getDataRange();//THIS GETS EVERYTHING, I DON'T THINK IT CAN TAKE A SUBRANGE
      objects = getRowsData(mainSheet, main_range,3);


    output = [];
      for (i in objects) {
        var obj=objects[i]
        output.push(obj);

      }

        Logger.log(output);

    return output;

  }
```

With the goal of populating the selectbox on the client side, But I'm getting the error in the title . How can I send the objects over from server to client sides ?

Comment: Does your spreadsheet contain dates? Those aren't supported as return values by [script.run method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). (Also, about your comment about `.getDataRange();` not taking a subrange; indeed it doesn't, if you want a subrange, use `.getRange(...)`)

Comment: Thank you, yes my spreadsheet has dates, what would you suggest?

Comment: Convert them to strings before returning...

Comment: I'm interested to see how you do this. Do you use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() ?

Comment: Depends on circumstances. JSON is one way. Or maybe you just need stringified dates on the receiving end, to build HTML from? Then Utilities.formatDate may be appropriate. Then again, do you want the times to be displayed in the user's local timezone, which the Apps Script won't know?

Comment: Thanks, In my case I was able to get it working with JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

Javascript:

```
 $(function() {
        $('#txt1').val('');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
          .getSelectOptions();
      });

function updateSelect(vA)
{
  var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
  select.options.length = 0; 
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
  }
}
```

Google Apps Script:

```
function getSelectOptions()
{
  sortOptions();
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that example really helped me!

Comment: I have some more simple examples on my website [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/dont-give-up-yet).

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.